# Why $BV[a,b]$ is not separable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, bounded-variation

How can I prove that $BV([a,b])$ is not separable. Here, $BV([a,b])$ means all the function defined on $[a,b]$ with finite total variation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total varation distance between $I_{(x, \frac  {1+x} 2)}$ and $I_{(y, \frac  {1+y} 2)}$ is $1$ whenever $x \neq y$ ($x,y \in (0,1)$). Hence the  space is not separable.

Comment: Thanks for your hint ! Another question is, how can I prove a space is not separable generally?

Comment: @Kepler If you can find uncountably many points separated by some positive distance then the space is not separable.